# Text replacement in Apple Pages document using AppleScript

Tags: replace, applescript

I need to replace hundreds of non-superscripted commas that appear between two superscripted one-, two-, or three-digit numbers by a superscripted comma in an Apple Pages document. What's the best way or at least a good way to do this in AppleScript? (Based on what I read, AppleScript should be able to do this and normally I would teach myself, but because of a fast-approaching deadline, I do not have time to do so.)

Thanks for your help.